# Content Management Systems for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Currently have developed a .NET CMS for my web portal. Can the same CMS be used for the iphone application with the help of XMLParsing or should develop a new CMS in xcode. I am new to iphone development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMS should be developed in server side. iPhone App is recommended to act as a mobile interface for fetching data from server side & sending commands to server side.

Communication in-between can use XML or JSON or even SOAP .

Comment: Now can I use the same .NET CMS which is in the server side and use XML for communication